# CSS3 - Help creating two specific div shapes that are 100% page width (see attached image)

Tags: css, width, shapes, fill, angle

I am getting the hang of CSS3 fairly well, but I am working on a design that requires a background like this:

[image: Preview of Background]

The preview above is intended to be 100% width and height of the browser window, and I figured  I'd set the background color to #f0f0f0 (the lightest grey color, all the way the bottom of preview), and then I'd need to create the large white div that has a point, and give that drop shadow. But I cannot figure out how to get the div to be full width and height, and give the bottom side that angle/arrow point. I don't even know where the heck to start. ANY help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Please & thank you!

Comment: I think your are looking for something like a shaped div. Check this link (http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). It has the CSS you can use for shaping the div.

Comment: The chevron shape they provided worked very well! Simple to implement and tweak as well. Awesome resource, they have some neat shapes available. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0 }
</style>
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-image: myimage.svg; background-position: bottom;"></div> <!--viewport width and viewport height-->
```

Then you just have to make a simple svg. Also, you can consider making the svg inline. And since I'm nice, here:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 5" fill="#ccc">
    <path d="M 0,5 L 10,0 L 20,5 Z"/>
</svg>
```